# Laravel-Elixir with Bootstrap SASS and Compass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, laravel-5, compass, laravel-elixir

I want to use Bootstrap SASS and Compass in Laravel 5.

For this, I need to install Bower and add the packages like:

> bootstrap-sass-official

But I'm not finding the official Compass package for install by Bower.

Which the official Compass package to Bower?

Or it doesn't exist?

[image: Bower Compass search results]

Comment: Reminder to not use the elixir tag as it is about the elixir programming language.

Comment: Thanks! I meant Laravel-Elixir, a feature available in Laravel 5 [laravel elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way to resolve a problem that I had before. It was the *gem compass*.

[install Compass](https://gist.github.com/stephou0104/233b5c99884f1d8c8b8b)

Once installed, there are more steps.

Install npm laravel-elixir-sass-compass

[laravel-elixir-sass-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-sass-compass)

```
npm install laravel-elixir-sass-compass
```

if you are using Twitter Bootstrap, you can follow the great post down:

[Setting up Laravel Elixir with Bootstrap](https://laravel-news.com/2014/10/setting-laravel-elixr-bootstrap/)

My final gulpfile.js:

[image: gulpfile.js]

And my app.scss:

[image: app.scss]

Thanks!